# I want to join 3 tables and select 1 coulmn from each table

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have tried using join as follows but it is not working

```
SELECT distinct(udf.FIELD_NAME),fun.FUNCTION_ID,mo.MODULE AS PRODUCT_MODULE FROM TABLE1 udf
JOIN TABLE2 mo
ON udf.PRODUCT_CODE = mo.PRODUCT_CODE
JOIN TABLE3 fun
ON udf.FIELD_NAME = fun.FIELD_NAME
where (udf.product_code in (select mo.product_code from TABLE2 mo))AND(udf.FIELD_NAME like '%UDF%')AND(udf.FIELD_NAME IN(SELECT fun.FIELD_NAME FROM TABLE3 fun));
```

I want all the where conditions mentioned here to work

Answer (score 0):

There are some statements in your WHERE clause that mimic the join condition. If you do a join like this

```
JOIN TABLE2 mo
ON udf.PRODUCT_CODE = mo.PRODUCT_CODE
```

then there is no need to add the WHERE clause

```
where (udf.product_code in (select mo.product_code from TABLE2 mo))
```

because those 2 do the same. Unless you have duplicate rows, the "DISTINCT" clause is not needed either. Your query can be rewritten as:

```
SELECT
  udf.field_name,
  fun.function_id,
  mo.module AS product_module
  FROM
  table1   udf
    JOIN table2   mo ON udf.product_code = mo.product_code
    JOIN table3   fun ON udf.field_name = fun.field_name
 WHERE
  udf.field_name LIKE '%UDF%';
```